# Xcode - iOS 4 system messages appear in wrong localization (English even though language is set to German)

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm building an iPad app for a German customer. The app is not planned to support any languages other than German so I didn't use any of Xcode's localization functionality but simply hard coded the strings.

My problem is the following: The entire app now is in German except for the system messages that (I suspect) come from iOS itself like copy, paste, cut in a text field. This happens in spite of the language of iOS being set to German in the system preferences. I always thought the handling of that was entirely up to the user so that he would see those kinds of messages in whatever language he chose in the system preferences. Apparently that's not the case.

Can anyone give me a hint what I need to change in order to have those messages displayed in German?

TIA!